# Can I install the free Windows 7/8 -> 10 upgrade on a new empty drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-installation, windows-10-upgrade

With the new Windows 10 coming out soon as a free upgrade, I'd like to know if and how I can install the upgrade on a new HDD. I assume the files needed for Windows 10 are only for upgrading an installed copy of Windows 7 or 8 and not a standalone installer to use on an empty hard drive. Or is this assumption wrong?

I have some issues booting (an older non-working version appears in the list of OS's to choose from) and I'd like to replace my current SSD, which is too small, with a new larger capacity one, while keeping my other drives intact. The old SSD will then be removed.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> With the new Windows 10 coming out soon as a free upgrade, I'd like to
>   know if and how I can install the upgrade on a new HDD. I assume the
>   files needed for Windows 10 are only for upgrading an installed copy
>   of Windows 7 or 8 and not a standalone installer to use on an empty
>   disc. Or is this assumption wrong?

You will be able to do this provided on the machine the new HDD will be installed in, upgrade an existing installation of either Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, from there you can perform a clean installation if you want.

Microsoft has released installation media for Windows 10 (Version 1507) and Windows 10 (Version 1511), once you have accepted the **free upgrade**, you will be able to install Windows 10 from that installation media straight to a new HDD if you want.

I strongly advise you to solve your existing problem before you accept the upgrade.

### Source Material

> **Can I perform a clean install using the Free upgrade?**
>
> No, it will require that you are running a previous qualifying version and start
>   the upgrade from within the qualifying version. You can initiate a
>   clean install after completing the Upgrade.
>
> Please be aware that you cannot use the free upgrade offer to perform
>   a clean install on first attempt. You must first upgrade from the
>   qualifying version of Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1 (whether you do it
>   through Windows Update or using the .ISO file). Ensure the upgrade is
>   completed successfully and then ensure that it is activated.
>
> You can then proceed to do a clean install by using recovery media or
>   using the Reset function in Start > Settings > Update & Security >
>   Recovery > Reset this PC (Get Started).
>
> **I have multiple computers, do I have to download Windows 10 on each computer?**
>
> You can download a .ISO file and upgrade each computer
>   offline. The ISO should be available by the time Windows 10
>   launches.**

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9)

### Download Windows 10

- [Windows 10 32-bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616935)
- [Windows 10 64-bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616936)

### Version 1511

As of Windows 10 Version 1511 (Build 10586) released on November 9, 2015 you can now use previous eligible versions of Windows to install and activate Windows 10.  You are still limited by the July 29th 2016 for the purposes of activation.  Once Windows 10 is activated on a system it no longer requires a license key when installed, and will automatically activate, through digital entitlement.  Retail copies however, of Windows 10, still require a license key at 
installation time.

### Windows 10 Tech Bench

[image]

[Windows 10 ISO Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench)

### Additional Reading

1. [How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10 ISO file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43)
2. [Installing Windows 10 using the media creation tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install?ocid=ms_wol_win10)
3. [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/872621#872621)

Comment: @RogUE - There is nothing to discuss about this answer.  I have answered your question(s) you submitted as comments to other questions.  *There isn't anything to discuss.*

Comment: Wait a minute. Will those .ISOs work for OEM licenses?

Comment: @RogUE - **Of course they will.**  Generic Windows 7 .ISOs, which can also be downloaded at the TestBench website, will work with OEM copies of Windows 7 despite the incorrect information reported saying that generic Windows 7 .ISOs don't work with OEM Windows 7 licences..  *Granted you have to do something to a configuration file that exists within the .ISO in that case though.*

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

***But you will require a previous qualified version***

> **I downloaded the .ISO file but I am being prompted to enter a product key when I start setup.**
>
> Please note: The copy of Windows 10 you download must correspond with
> the edition of Windows you are upgrading from:
>
> - Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium, Windows 8.0 Core, Windows 8.1 Core must use a Windows 10 Home ISO
> - Windows 7 Professional, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 8.0 Pro, Windows 8.1 Pro must use a Windows 10 Pro ISO
> - Your currently installed copy of Windows must be activated. If its not, you will be prompted to enter a product key.
> - If you are using Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 8.0 Enterprise, Windows 8.1 Enterprise editions, you won't be able to do this unless
> - you have access to a volume license program.

Windows 10 Upgrade Licence will stay valid and with the Final release you will avaliable to download the `.iso` File.

> This is more than a one-time upgrade: once a Windows device is
> upgraded to Windows 10, we will continue to keep it current for the
> supported lifetime of the device –at no additional charge.

*Terry Myerson*

There is the complete information:

[FAQ Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9)