# Can i CHOOSE to delete my files during the windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows

So, i heard windows 10 was coming out, and since my computer is fairly slow from junk files, i want to know if i can choose to not bring over my files? So basically, i got some mods (Pay Day 2) that conflict with each other. I want to start over, because i don't know who's what and if we're in there or that we're out here, or if he's the sheriff, or if we're out here.
I just remembered.
We're out here. What i want to know is wheres the caveman?

Comment: You must upgrade your existing installation at least once, once you do that, you can reset the "Reset" feature to wipe your personal files or if you want use the [.ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to perform a clean install of Windows 10.  If you want to be able to activate your installation, and have a legitimate installation, you must perform the upgrade then perform the clean install.  [This isn't an exact duplicate but it is close enough.](http://superuser.com/questions/946348/can-i-install-the-free-windows-7-8-10-upgrade-on-a-new-empty-drive/946355#946355)

Answer (score 1):

First time round, you will end up carrying some junk over as the install is an upgrade.

As soon as the install is complete, you have 2 options:

1) you can chose the "reset" option to reset your machine to factory:
[image]

2) fresh format and clean install.  Once activated, your Windows 10 key is good for clean installs as well as upgrades.

EDIT: as Ramhound very rightly pointed out, once Windows 10 is activated once, through the upgrade procedure, future installations will automatically be activated provided it is the same machine. Each machine is independent from one another, all license rights and limitations, remain the same with Windows 10.

(To Ramhound, apologies for stealing your comment.  It was worded so well that I couldn't think of a better or more efficient way of phrasing it myself and felt it could only benefit an answer.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: - Your 2) Statement is a little confusing.  You should clarify that once Windows 10 is activated once, through the upgrade procedure, future installations will automatically be activated provided it is the same machine.  Each machine is independent from one another, all license rights and limitations, remain the same with Windows 10.

Comment: Absolutely correct, answer updated.  have stolen most of your comment as it was worded perfectly and I couldn't think of a way to reword or improve on it whatsoever.

Comment: Really...Great....Edit....!

Comment: Thank you, since i wanted to restart and i heard it would carry over, i found it was like a slap to the face, that i'll never have what i desire. Well, without doing it the hard way.

Comment: Not a problem.  If this has helped, please upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer for others reference